# Definition of temperature without thermal equilibrium condition

Tags: statistical-mechanics, temperature, definition, non-equilibrium

Is [temperature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temperature) only defined in thermal equilibrium? Then how can we explain heat flow by temperature differences?

Comment: $T^{-1} \equiv dS/dE$. You can look this up on e.g. Wikipedia.

Comment: It is proportional to the average kinetic energy of the molecules divided by the boltzmann constant, if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the temperature differences are "smooth" enough, i.e., locally there is a reasonable definition of temperature (local equilibrium), then the temperature gradient determines the heat flux. In the opposite case, it is molecular kinetics who determines the energy transfer. The latter happens much faster and local equilibrium gets established quickly.

Comment: Thanks! How about case of quantum statistics? If there is a particle in specific quantum state, there is a probability for each energy eigenstate correspond to the energy eigenvalue. When this distribution follows Maxwell-Boltzmann, Fermi-Dirac, or Bose-Einstein statistics(it may mean the particle is in equilibrium with reservoir), we can  find out temperature of the particle from that. For that case, what if equilibrium vanish?

Comment: In case of quantum statistics the principle of local equilibrium holds. There is a notion of a large-scale entropy, there are the corresponding master equation and transport equations. There are no pure states, but mixtures.